# Functions other than imported doesn't work inside type='module' script

Tags: javascript, html, express, import, export

Why the functions declared in type module script don't work and only imported functions do?

I have an HTML file in which there's a script tag:

```
<script type='module' src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

In scripts.js file I am importing a function from a different file:

```
import {bfs} from "./algorithms.js"
```

If i try to use that function in script.js file, everything works. However inside this script.js file, I have different, not imported functions, like so:

```
function mouseMoved() {
  console.log('mouse moved') };
```

When I run the express server, i get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mouseMoved is not defined
> at HTMLTableCellElement.onmousemove

But when I delete "type='module'" property from the script tag inside HTML, like so:

```
<script src="javascripts/script.js"></script>
```

Then function declared inside this script, like mouseMoved() works perfectly. However the script tag needs to have type='module' attribute in order to make imports work.

I've searched and watched couple of videos explaining modules, but I did not find answer to my problem. I really would love to know how to handle modules in relation to main script tag in HTML file, so that I can important functions inside main script, but also use functions declared in that script.

Comment: When your script is a module, functions at the outer layer of thee file are **not** global functions, and they therefore cannot be used from "onsomething" event handlers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Can I ask you, if there's other way than making each function global in such file? Is there other way to use imports in main script without making it a module and thus preventing need to make every declared function global?

Comment: Well, you *could* explicitly export the functions from `scripts.js` by assigning them as properties of the `window` object, but one of the basic points of using modules is to *avoid* polluting the global namespace. My opinion is that it's far better to separate the binding of event handling from HTML markup (i.e., use `.addEventListener()` etc), though I'm not a React person and I realize that React changes the landscape (probably other frameworks too).

Comment: That's the answer i needed. Thank you :).